# How to get remote server facts on ansible

Tags: deployment, ansible

I have playbook where i setup web-servers.
And in this playbook i want to know local-network ip address of db server.

All this servers i have in inventory file.

How i can do it?

I tried to use hostvars, but they have only local server facts.

Answer (score 3):

## Hostvars and remote variables

It's possible to reference variables on remote servers using hostvars.  For example, let's say you're running a play on a server in your web-servers group. You can reference variables on your db-server in the playbook like this:

```
{{ hostvars['db-server.example.com']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
```

Be advised that for this to work you must already have talked to db-server.example.com in the current play or another play higher up in the playbook.  Ansible 1.8, (still in development at the time of writing) will remedy this by implementing optional [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching), which will allow you to save facts between playbook runs.

Comment: But if i doesn't interact i can't do it?
I thought that ansible has command to go to the remote server from repository and take it facts. Ok. Thanks

Comment: And about fact caching. It isn't i good idea(if i understood this correctly). Fact caching it is just cache for improve speed! This cache can be expired. For example, i setup my db severs, setup web-servers using fact cache. It's ok. But if i need to update my web-servers after 1 week, it will fall because cache is empty.

Comment: All you need to do is make sure that Ansible has already talked to the db-server before you try to run a play on another server that references a fact on the db server.  You could for example have an earlier play that runs and uses Ansible's [setup module](http://docs.ansible.com/setup_module.html) to gather facts on the db-server.